# React DocViewer is not working jpeg format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

```
 <DocViewer pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} documents={docs} />
```

this is how i use this build

[I return like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by6ab.png)

[Since the data comes in this format(base64), I translate it this way

this is how i get the link(blob:http://localhost:3000/88a28c02-d6ed-406a-85e3-a62c3ba23f71)

[but ı am getting error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by6ab.png)

Comment: can you please share the error that you are encountering ?

Comment: I shared (but ı am getting error like this)

Comment: can you also share the function that you are using to convert base64 to blob?

Comment: The blob  correct. The problem is that the doc is not reading this link

Comment: FYI the documents object should be like this: [{uri: 'your uri'}]

Comment: Also there should be network request in your network tab that you can monitor.

Comment: a different pdf,doc.image viewer. Can you suggest a plugin?

Comment: i think the plugin that you have provided should already include jpeg.

Comment: but is not working.I wonder  ı use to blob.Blob local 
can it replace